# How do I defeat the 3rd boss?

Tags: android, soft-pixel-dungeon

I came to the 3rd boss in [Soft Pixel Dungeon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wolispace.softdpixeldungeon&hl=en). I had a Battle Axe 12+3 and Mail Armor 10+5 and DO300, yet the boss still kills me in two hits.

Please help, I have saved the game on Level 14 just before I go a level lower.

Comment: ...what game are you talking about exactly? Might want to add that in the tags, and you may also want to improve your formatting and make the title less obscure.

Comment: @Texenox He has the name of the game both in the title and in the first sentence of his question. Don't be so quick to judge. This site is a **community-driven** Q&A platform; if a new user has some issues, help format their question or guide them along

Comment: @howdareyou Fair enough, I see now. I guess maybe I am a bit quick to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Store up health potions in the levels above.  Start with throwing anything at the boss that will set the boss on fire.  Then stand next to the boss and repeatedly wack it with your weapon.  If you have anything that can poison the boss, use that too.  Judge the average amount of damage the boss deals and when your health gets within the danger zone, drink a health potion.  Every time the fire goes out on the boss, toss another thing at the boss that will set it on fire again.  Don't run from the boss as it heals itself every time it moves.  Eventually, because it is taking damage both from fire and from your melee weapon the boss will die.  Hopefully it will die before you run out of health potions.  Once it is dead, step away and wait for the poison cloud to disperse before going back to where it died and picking up the key it dropped.